# Compound interest with recursion: Hey guys, idk why it says my return function is error?

Tags: recursion, p5.js

I don't know why it says my return function

```
recursion(M, rate, day - 1) * (100.0 + rate) / 100
```

has an error? And btw M is amount and StartM is startamount.

```
var M; 
var StartM = 10000; 
var rate = 0.01;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);

    function recursion(M, rate, day) {
        if (day == 0)
            return 1;  
        else
            return function recursion(M, rate, day-1) * (100.0 + rate)/100

        print(day + "   "+ M);
    }

    function draw() {
        background(220);
    }
}
```

Comment: return function recursion doesn't seem like valid syntax, try without function word

Comment: i tried but it doesnt work, there is no error sign, but it wont print out in console

Comment: are you calling that function somewhere ?

Comment: under create canvas, if thats what you mean?

Comment: you defined function , you also need to call it, i posted snippet below how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Remove function word from return. Also, you have to call your recursion function.

```
var M; 
var StartM = 10000; 
var rate = 0.01;
function setup() {
createCanvas(400, 400);
  draw()
  recursion(StartM,rate,10)
function recursion(M, rate, day){
  print(day)
if(day == 0)
return 1;  
else

return  recursion(M, rate, day-1) * (100.0 + rate)/100

print(day + "   "+ M);

}

function draw() {
background(220);
} 
}
```